# How to assign one table data height to another table data

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to give same height for different table data.

```
var p = $("#our_table td");
$("#our_table td").text(p.innerHeight());
var q = $(".left-table td");
$(".left-table td").text(q.innerHeight());
$("#our_table td").text(p.innerHeight()) == $(".left-table td").text(q.innerHeight());
```

Comment: do you want to swap height of tables?

Comment: need to give second table data height to first table data

Answer (score 0):

Use `.css()` in jquery

```
$("#our_table td").css("height" , $(".left-table td").innerHeight());
```

or `.height()` in jquery

```
$("#our_table td").height($(".left-table td").innerHeight());
```